# Async WCF call not always successfully when silverlight app is closing

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight app running in a browser as part of an overall ASP.NET website. I'm doing some event logging from it (tracking some UI click events and such).

I have a WCF service set up to create DB log records, and obviously the Silverlight app is calling it asynchronously.

This all works just fine, until I try to fire off a call to the logging service at the tail end of the app life. That is, when the user clicks a certain button, the silverlight calls some javascript on the website to redirects to another page, so the silverlight app closes, and then only sometimes do the last logger calls get through.

I am assuming it has something to do with the shutdown procedure of silverlight, and that it is a timing issue whereby sometimes the WCF channel is still open and the message gets through, and sometimes the channel closes and the logging doesn't occur.

Regardless of whether or not the logging occurs, the callback never fires for this last logger call.

As part of the handler for the last closing click event, the silverlight app calls this:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("ViewEmployersPageWithMenu();")
```

Which, as I understand it, will trigger an exit of the silverlight app as the browser is navigating away from it.

Just before doing this, I fire off a simple logger call to my async wCF service.

I believe silverlight doesn't allow async service calls during its exit handling, is this the case? If there a different way I should be handling this o get that log call out successfully before the app closes?

Answer (score 0):

If the logging is that important and considered an integral part of the application, you could hold off on calling the JavaScript function until the callback of the logging request.  It may cause some delay in the execution of the redirect as it is now waiting for the WCF request to round-trip, but perhaps that is preferred to missing the log.

If you can replicate the issue, I would be curious to how Fiddler sees the series of requests (logging request and redirect request) when it works compared to when it does not.  That may show that the browser is canceling the log request when it executes the redirect.